# For loop array of dictionaries

Tags: swift

I have plist which contains array of dictionaries.

Each dictionary has several columns.

I would like to access the each data of dictionary wito for loop.

```
var qplist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
// qplist  is array of dictionary

 for meta in qplist! { //Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
     //meta['test']
 }
```

How can I loop the array of dictionary??

I guess something like this ,,,, but its doesnt work.

```
for var meta:Dictionary in qplist! {
```

Comment: you need to use var qplist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as [[String:Any]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
if let qplist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path),
   let array = qplist.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]] {   
    for dictionary in array { 
        print(dictionary["test"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have succeeded in Casting array of Dictionary.

Comment: @whitebear Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you need to  do it:

```
  if let  qplist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String : Any]]{
     for meta in qplist {
         //meta['test']
     }
  }
```

Comment: You really should use optional binding on `qplist` just in case there is no file at the path or the plist at the path doesn't actually contain an array of dictionary.